# Date Time Format In Data

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a JSON data, and in it have attribute `start date` with value **`2016-04-09T03:00:00+07:00`**. I know 2016-04-09 is the current date, +07:00 is my GMT timezone. My current date time I check by Javascript is `Sat Apr 09 2016 01:50:10 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)` But I don't know what is `T03:00:00`?

Anyone can explain to me what is it? Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

Hours, minutes, and seconds. Its an [ISO 8601 date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 0):

From:  https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00 corresponds to November 5, 1994, 8:15:30 am, US Eastern Standard Time.

Thus,

2016-04-09T03:00:00+07:00 corresponds to April 9, 2016, 3:00:00 am, GMT+7 Standard Time is 7 hours ahead of Greenwich Mean Time (GMT+7) (Cambodia, etc.)